# How do I capture character keyboard buttons pressed in video fullscreen mode

Tags: jquery, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm using a HTML5 jw player 6.. Is it possible to capture character keyboard buttons pressed in fullscreen mode?

I have tried using

```
$("body").keyup(function(e) {
    div.innerHTML = e.keyCode;
});
```

But it seems to register only certain keys pressed (such as space, key right, key left etc) and no characters. I'd like to record normal characters such as the letter "a" being pressed down during playback...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not fully implimented in all browsers, but this dev article from Opera should give you the details you need.
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/#scripting

Comment: Ok, shit, it's a browser limitation.. So you can't really do anything about this then it seems. No overruling?